# Is there a standard method to filter all items

Tags: swift, functional-programming, swift3

I have an API that takes an `isIncluded` parameter, which is then passed to a `filter`. I want to include every item, so I wrote this:

```
object.read(isIncluded: { _ in true })
```

This doesn't feel satisfying to me. I wanted somethings more expressive, so I wrote the following function.

```
func always<T>(t: T) -> Bool { return true }
```

So I have a very nice

```
object.read(isIncluded: always)
```

Then I thought there should be a built-in to do exactly this, but I can't find one.

Am I missing something in the standard library. Is there a better way to compose this in the standard library?

Comment: The Swift standard library tries to achieve the minimum level of functionality required to achieve Swifts goals. This way the runtime binary is small when shipped with an app (which is necessary until ABI stability is achieved), and implementing the library is easier. They avoid writing things like this that are trivial to implement yourself. (There's also no identity function, for example, because just writing `{$0}` is pretty trivial)

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the parameter definition from your closure, so you can shorten your first example to this:

```
object.read(isIncluded:{true})
```

Answer (score 0):

For cases where you don't want to filter, maybe just provide a default:

```
func read(isIncluded: (Object) -> Bool = {true}) { ... }
```

Then you can just call it as `Object.read()` without having to include that `isIncluded: {true}` filter.